# SQL query from many to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have many to many relation

```
  table:  images    
  id  imageName  
   1    pic01
   2    pic02
   3    pic03    

  table:  imagesKeywords
  imageId  keywordId
   1        2
   1        3
   1        4
   2        3
   3        1
   3        4
   3        2

  table:  keywords
  id  keywordName  
   1    car
   2    tree
   3    cat
   4    phone
```

Each image has some keywords, and different images can have the same keyword.

I need to make a search for images , they have a specific `keywordName`'s.

example-1:   search for **car** and **phone**

the result should be : **pic03**

example-2:    search for **tree** and **phone**

the result should be : **pic01**,  **pic03**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to want `JOIN` with `GROUP BY` Clause :

```
select i.imageName
from images i inner join
     imagesKeywords ik 
     on ik.imageId = i.id inner join 
     keywords k
     on k.id = ik.keywordId 
where k.keywordName in ('car', 'phone')
group by i.imageName
having count(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, this should work:

```
select i.imageName as name from keywords k
join imagesKeywords iK on k.id = iK.keywordId
join images i on iK.imageId = i.id
group by i.imageName;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution,

```
with subquery as
       (select i1.imageName, k1.keywordName from keywords k1 join imagekeywords ik1 on k1.id=ik1.keywordId join images i1 on i1.id = ik1.imageId )    
 select a.imageName from subquery a join subquery b on a.imageName=b.imageName where a.keywordName ='car' and b.keywordName='phone';
```